# Google script forward only inbox with big attachments

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I was looking in the database and could not find what is was looking for
I'm looking for a script that only forwards the new messages in the Gmail inbox.
i tried to modife this script.

```
function RespondEmail() {

  //send response email
  var threads = GmailApp.search("to:be01acd@pf.cofep.be is:unread");
  var subject = "";
  var msg = "";
  var c = 0; // will be used to count the messages in each thread
  var t = "";
  var attachment = "";
  var forwarded = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5 /*threads.length*/ ; i++) { 
    // I set 'i' to 3 so that you can test the function on your 3 most recent unread emails.
    // to use it on all your unread email, remove the 3 and remove the /* and */ signs.                   

    t = threads[i]; // I wanted to avoid repetition of "threads[i]" for the next 2 lines haha
    c = t.getMessageCount() - 1;
    msg = t.getMessages()[c];
    forwarded = msg.getBody(); // that is the body of the message we are forwarding.

    subject = msg.getSubject();
    attachment = msg.getAttachments();

    msg.forward("destination@gmail.com", {
      replyTo: "origin@gmail.com",
      subject: "TPS report status of [" + subject + "]", // customizes the subject
      htmlBody: "<br><br>" //adds your message to the body
        +
        "<div style='text-align: center;'>---------- Doorgestuurd bericht Gmail ----------</div><br>" + forwarded, //centers
      attachments: attachment
    });
    t.markRead(); // mark each forwarded thread as read, one by one

  }
}
```

But it failed I added label:inbox and it blocks on the thread count.
also, this inbox gets messages with big attachments added to them.
and this script blocks when there is an attachment.

could somebody help me out ?

Kind Regards 
Nigel.

Comment: Have you ever tried checking the [Gmail documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads) on how to deal with attachments? Also have you checked the [Apps Script documentation for Gmail attachments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment)?